# Pass Array of pointers to arrays to function where malloc() will occur

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, malloc

I've been avoiding this situation by running malloc() outside the function, but in reality the function knows how big the arrays need to be and the outside can't know how big the arrays need to be.

What I have: uint8_t *jpg[6], which is six pointers to six jpg compressed images which will be malloc-ed by the code that reads in the files. To put it another way this is an array of six pointers to six arrays of indeterminate size.

I have been trying to figure out how to pass the pointer to the pointers into the function so it can malloc() the memory with the known sizes of the jpg data.

I have tried many things but can't get anything to compile.

My latest attempt looks like this and I don't understand why it doesn't work:

Main code:

```
...
uint8_t *jpg[6];
int size[6]; // returns the size of the images in bytes.
LoadJPG(&jpg, size);
...
```

Function:

```
LoadJPG(uint8_t ***jpg, int *size)
{
  ...
  *jpg = (uint8_t *) malloc(blahblahblah);
  ...
  memcpy(**jpg, *indata, blahblahblah);
  ...
}
```

Error points to the function call and function:

```
error: argument of type "uint8_t *(*)[6]" is incompatible with parameter of type "uint8_t ***"
```

I'm compiling with gcc 4.9.4

Comment: 1. Learn the difference between pointers and arrays.  2. Don't use malloc in C++.  3. Don't use pass-by-pointer in C++  4. (advanced) don't use raw pointers or C-style arrays at all

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know I'm using a mix a C and C++. I'm doing what works because I'm learning. I still don't have an answer though.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ it is undefined behaviour to write into malloc'd space without also creating objects in it. You mention you're learning - a good way to learn is to use simple, idiomatic C++ code.

The program could look like:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

void LoadJPG( std::array<std::vector<uint8_t>, 6> &jpgs )
{
    jpgs[0].resize(12345);
    // use std::copy or memcpy to copy into &jpgs[0][0]

    jpgs[1].resize(23456);
    // etc.
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::vector<uint8_t>, 6> jpgs;

    LoadJPG(jpgs);
}
```

Comment: That's beautiful. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are confused like I was, the right way to do it with C structures (in case you're using something antiquated like CudaC and don't want to spend all eternity converting C++ structures to C structures) is really pretty obvious and I feel pretty dumb for not realizing it until this morning.

main:

```
uint8_t *jpg[CAMERAS];
int size[CAMERAS];
GetRawImagesFromCamera(jpg, size);
...
free(jpg[]);
```

function:

```
void GetRawImagesFromCamera(uint8_t **jpg, int *size)
...
for (i=0; i < CAMERAS; i++)
{
  jpg[i] = (uint8_t *) malloc(size[i]);
  memcpy((void *) jpg[i], (void *) buff[i], size[i]);
  ...
}
...
```

This works because arrays are passed by a pointer to the first element. I had convinced myself that I needed to pass a pointer to the pointers, but that's exactly what gets passed when you pass an array.